# Why does Elixir need `Flow`? Isn't that handled by BEAM by default?

Tags: erlang, elixir

After seeing José Valim's last keynote speech about `Flow & GenStage` I became confused because:
1) If Flow & GenStage is being added to Elixir is because it really makes sense to improve concurrency;
2) on the other hand I had in my mind that one of the key Erlang/BEAM strengths was that it was concurrent/used all cores by default and a developer should not worry about that.
So, if `Flow & GenStage` is not (yet) to help with distributed systems running on different machines, could someone explain the differences between `Flow`and the native Erlang/BEAM concurrency?

Comment: In Erlang you can send as many messages as you like to a given "process/pid" - but if you send too many they just get queued by the VM - and clog up memory.  Managing these queues is a "black art" - step in Flow - which makes sure that the receiving process/pid is not going to be overloaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Flow` and `GenStage` address a different problem than just concurrency.

What always happens in distributed systems is that once you have easy concurrency, you eventually run into the "thundering herd" problem where a single process or a small group of processes becomes a bottleneck for all the other processes in the system. This video is demonstrates the problem clearly.

https://youtu.be/8NPzLBSBzPI

The key concept of `Flow` and `GenStage` is back-pressure in the system to prevent the overflow of incoming requests to the workers. This back-pressure concept allows you to either add more workers or slow down the assembly line.

These modules are attempts to generalize the problem of self-scheduling that every sufficiently large BEAM application runs into. There have already been many one-off implementations of the ideas in them to allow BEAM applications to fail gracefully in the face of large loads.

Comment: I agree. But that is in distributed systems and José Valim presents the case where you're talking about a single system in just one machine. I also understand the advantages of back-pressure. What is missing is how Erlang/BEAM handles it now that makes this necessary even when it is presented as the key distinctive factor of Erlang. That piece is what I miss.

Comment: The BEAM is a distributed system that just happens to run on one machine or 100 machines.

Comment: Think of `Flow` and `GenStage` as pieces of tech that take direct and concrete advantage of the more generic approach of Erlang/BEAM which, if used poorly, will lead to poor results. They are tools tailored for a class of applications and scenarios.